# python script for to decode track data encrypted with DataKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, dukpt

I am having troubling with generating IPEK from BDK and KSN from python, after that i want to generate dataKey from kSN and IPEK. Is there any way to do this two functions using python?
Wanted Scenario below

```
def decryptinfo(ksn, data):
  BDK = unhexlify("0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210")
  ksn = unhexlify(ksn)
  IPEK = GenerateIPEK(ksn, BDK)
  DATAKEY = GetDataKey(ksn, IPEK)
  res = TDES_Dec(data, DATA_KEY)
  return hexlify(res)

def GetDataKey(ksn, ipek):
  key = GetDukptKey(ksn, ipek)
  key = bytearray(key)
  key[5] ^= 0xFF
  key[13] ^= 0xFF
 return str(key)
```

I want to know is there any way to get  GenerateIPEK(ksn, BDK) and  GetDukptKey(ksn, ipek) from python..

Comment: other than just writing them?

Comment: When you do, bear in mind some DUKPT implementations (including those used by HSMs) use different value than what you currently have - in many cases DUKPT data key is encrypted by itself as a last step (you would need to add this in GetDataKey).

Answer (score 0):

he code provided in the GitHub repository you shared uses an older version of the pycryptodome library, and it seems to work with Python 2. If you are using Python 3, refer the example code

https://github.com/allen246/dukpt/blob/main/example.py

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35362812)